# Does the name 'Quark' have a different meaning in Ferengi culture?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

I was just considering the character of Quark and what an unusual name it was.  Of course a quark is a sub-atomic particle or the German word for cottage cheese, but it seems peculiar that a Ferengi, a race focused on profits, should be named after a sub-atomic particle.

The Ferengi have their own language of course which led me to wonder **does the name 'Quark' have any significance in Ferengi culture?** If there is no evidence regarding this in-universe, I would alternatively be interested in why, out-of-universe, it was decided to name a member of a species interested in profits after a sub-atomic particle.

Comment: Surely you mean "isn't it strange that a Ferengi is named after the German word for cottage cheese".

Comment: @EikePierstorff I wasn't aware of quark referring to cottage cheese - thank you for that point!

Comment: Brunt, Nog, Zek and Rom don't seem to have any common meaning other than sounding vaguely futuristic

Comment: @Richard Quite true.  I guess you could kind of say 'Rom' might have been a reference to a CD ROM?  Just a thought!

Comment: @N_Soong There are also other types of [read-only memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory).  Perhaps a joke on him being dumb?

Comment: @Richard:  why do you say so?   If we're discussing that Quark means cottage cheese then surely it is relevant that Nog means spiced egg drink.

Comment: You may wish to read the [interesting etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#Etymology) of the physics term "quark" on Wikipedia, as there's some depth to it, even beyond Joyce's *Finnegan's Wake* (from which Gell-Mann got the word).

Comment: Frankly I justed wanted to point out with my comment that there is only a limited number of syllables in human language and if you make stuff up some words are bound to sound like existing words (e.g. "Rom" sounds like the German name for the city of Rome, "brunt" is a perfectly ordinary english word, "Zek" sounds rather like an insult from Brunners "Stand on Zanzibar" (minus a "c") or , funnily enough, like the official abbreviation for the Zanzibar Electoral Commission etc.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A smattering of Ferengi words and their meanings have been [crystallized](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferengi_language) due to *TNG*, *DS9*, and various *Star Trek* novels, but unfortunately "Quark" is not one of these.

It is easier to find out-of-universe information regarding Quark's naming.  It seems that he might have been named after a 1970s television series:

> Quark, who often served as the show's comedy relief, may have been named after the **1978 television series *Quark***, which frequently examined science fiction themes from a humorous or satirical perspective.

([Source](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(Star_Trek)))

In particular, *Quark* — which was set in the 23rd Century — would frequently satirize *Star Trek*.  (See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(TV_series)) for episode descriptions.)